# Floor Plan Software

Tags: gratis, macos

I'm looking for free software that I can run on a Mac or browser that lets me import an existing architectural drawing (preferably in pdf format) that will then let me draw shapes representing furniture. The imported drawing is to scale so the software should be able to set the scale in feet and inches.

I've found programs that do 2D and 3D floor plans, but none yet that let me import a scaled drawing first. I only require 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one option. [Homestyler](https://www.homestyler.com/). Allows you to import a drawing as a background and set the scale. The import must be in JPEG or PNG format so ends up as a bitmap which isn't ideal, but it works well enough. Homestyler runs in a browser so is cross platform, however it refused to run in Safari so I had to use Chrome. Also, it uses up lots of screen real-estate with menus and such so would work better on a larger screen. Homestyler has a free tier and several paid options.